# Python post request, problem with posting

Tags: python, html, post, request

I'm trying to write a typeform bot but I am a totally beginner so I have problems with request.post

I am trying to fill this typeform: https://typeformtutorial.typeform.com/to/aA7Vx9
by this code

```
import requests

token = requests.get("https://typeformtutorial.typeform.com/app/form/result/token/aA7Vx9/default")

data = {"42758279": "true",
        "42758410": "text",
        "token": token}

r = requests.post("https://typeformtutorial.typeform.com/app/form/submit/aA7Vx9", data)

print(r)
```

I think that something is wrong with "data" and I am not sure if I use token in a good way. Could you help me?

Comment: Can you please share with us what is the result and why do thing that there is something wrong.

Comment: Try adding > data=json.dumps(data)  Like this
r = requests.post("https://typeformtutorial.typeform.com/app/form/submit/aA7Vx9", data=json.dumps(data))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first of all, you need to get another field with the token. To do that, you should pass the header `'accept': 'application/json'` in your first request.  In the response, you'll get the json object with the `token` and `landed_at` parameters. You should use them in the next step.

Then, the post data shoud be different from what you're passing. See the network tab in the browser's developer tools to find out the actual template. It has a structure like that:

```
{
    "signature": <YOUR_SIGNATURE>,
    "form_id": "aA7Vx9",
    "landed_at": <YOUR_LANDED_AT_TIME>,
    "answers": [
        {
            "field": {
                "id": "42758279",
                "type": "yes_no"
            },
            "type": "boolean",
            "boolean": True
        },
        {
            "field": {
                "id": "42758410",
                "type": "short_text"
            },
            "type": "text",
            "text": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

And finally, you should convert that json to text so the server would successfully parse it.

Working example:

```py
import requests
import json

token = json.loads(requests.post(
    "https://typeformtutorial.typeform.com/app/form/result/token/aA7Vx9/default",
    headers={'accept': 'application/json'}
).text)
signature = token['token']
landed_at = int(token['landed_at'])

data = {
    "signature": signature,
    "form_id": "aA7Vx9",
    "landed_at": landed_at,
    "answers": [
        {
            "field": {
                "id": "42758279",
                "type": "yes_no"
            },
            "type": "boolean",
            "boolean": True
        },
        {
            "field": {
                "id": "42758410",
                "type": "short_text"
            },
            "type": "text",
            "text": "1"
        }
    ]
}

json_data = json.dumps(data)

r = requests.post("https://typeformtutorial.typeform.com/app/form/submit/aA7Vx9", data=json_data)

print(r.text)
```

Output:

```py
{"message":"success"}
```

Comment: It looks like it doesn't work now. Please tell me how to get a token from typeform now?