# How do I get signature and landed_at data in typeform API?

Tags: typeform

It used to work like this:

```
import requests

u = "https://uza3fcl1odf.typeform.com/app/form/result/token/tCsWUtMB/default"
j = requests.post(u, headers={"Accept": "application/json"}).json()
# {'token': '20903331626f396431746f397777693832713331626f39643136747572367978706434313339363936363463366336363533373434333536343134353337366237613339343233303664373236613737353935613431363436393336343833313335333833383332333733393336333333373633653233363637346132653432343938383963326537663165326535633262373837326336613437343539666638653932613131393266386236393635626131353838323739363337', 'landed_at': '1588279637'}
```

**Also here are the topics about this:**

- [Post request to Typeform failing due to Invalid payload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58690281/7460038)
- [Python post request, problem with posting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58599595/7460038)
- [error with signature token when filling a typeform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61272853/7460038)
- [How to get JSON data from a Python POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61532103/7460038)

Here is my test form: https://uza3fcl1odf.typeform.com/to/tCsWUtMB

But now this solution does not work, I do not know why. What kind of POST request should I make to get "signature" and" landed_at " data in response?

*It is desirable that your example can be easily checked in Postman.*

Comment: The token is probably being generated via JavaScript.